# Allow (and correct the URL) when there is a special character such as %26 using IIS and the rewrite module

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7

I'm struggling with a legacy app that uses special characters like `%26` in the URL.  The characters don't affect the app but can't be changed, so I'm trying to get IIS to deal with them.

I've tried to ignore them [using multiple methods](http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/), but nothing seems to work.

So now I installed the IIS rewrite module and added a rewrite rule to *web.config* to replace the characters `%26` with `_`, for example:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ampersand" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*%26*" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}_{R:2}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is that IIS responds with "Bad Request" before the rewrite rule ever gets called.  So my question is this:  how can I change the order of precedence so that the mod rewrite filter will be called before IIS puts the ban hammer down on that URL?

Answer (score 1):

try changing the rule to:

```
<match url="(.*)%26(.*)" />
```